# What is the difference between `super(...)` and `return super(...)`?

Tags: python, oop

I'm just now learning about python OOP. In some framework's source code, i came across `return super(...` and wondered if there was a difference between the two.

```
class a(object):
    def foo(self):
        print 'a'

class b(object):
    def foo(self):
        print 'b'

class A(a):
    def foo(self):
        super(A, self).foo()

class B(b):
    def foo(self):
        return super(B, self).foo()

>>> aie = A(); bee = B()
>>> aie.foo(); bee.foo()
a
b
```

Looks the same to me. I know that OOP can get pretty complicated if you let it, but i don't have the wherewithal to come up with a more complex example at this point in my learning. Is there a situation where returning `super` would differ from calling `super`?

Comment: What is the difference between `"x"` and `return "x"`?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes. Consider the case where rather than just printing, the superclass's `foo` returned something:

```
class BaseAdder(object):
    def add(self, a, b):
        return a + b

class NonReturningAdder(BaseAdder):
    def add(self, a, b):
        super(NonReturningAdder, self).add(a, b)

class ReturningAdder(BaseAdder):
    def add(self, a, b):
        return super(ReturningAdder, self).add(a, b)
```

Given two instances:

```
>>> a = NonReturningAdder()
>>> b = ReturningAdder()
```

When we call `foo` on `a`, seemingly nothing happens:

```
>>> a.add(3, 5)
```

When we call `foo` on `b`, however, we get the expected result:

```
>>> b.add(3, 5)
8
```

That's because while both `NonReturningAdder` and `ReturningAdder` call `BaseAdder`'s `foo`, `NonReturningAdder` discards its return value, whereas `ReturningAdder` passes it on.

Comment: Ohh! I was reading this blog that gave me the impression that `super` was some python magic--conjured up to solve an inheritance problem with the "old style". Thanks for answering my silly question.

Comment: @Noob: Yes, `super` does do some magic in determining exactly what to call, but once it does call that other method, it acts just as you'd expect.

Comment: What is the use of `super` without return ?

Comment: @MichaelD A good example is `super().__init__()`, which can set or modify instance attributes, but `__init__` should not have a return value. Same would apply for any user-defined methods that modify attributes, but don't return anything (or where the return value isn't needed).