# Django override save method: to return super().save() or not to return?

Tags: django, django-models

I want to override model save method, but I've seen 2 types of codes:

1.

```
def save(self):
    # some code
    return super().save()
```

2. 

```
def save(self):
    #some code
    super().save()
```

When would we use return when without return?

Comment: its not a django related, its python syntax in general. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18649348/what-is-the-difference-between-super-and-return-super

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not use `return super().save(*args, **kwargs)`. Because save method does not return anything in Django's `models.Model` class. Here is the reference to [GitHub repository](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/base.py#L669). So you should always use:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    #some code
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
    # some more code
```

Comment: If we return it, nothing bad happens. And if some day in the future, Django decides to return something from `save`, we'd be returning that as well and no changes would be needed. No?